# Prove if $f$ is a concave function, then $f\left(\frac{ax_1+bx_2+cx_3}{a+b+c}\right)\geq \frac{af(x_1)+bf(x_2)+cf(x_3)}{a+b+c}.$

Tags: calculus

The question is

> **Prove: If $f$ is a concave function, then $$f\left(\frac{ax_1+bx_2+cx_3}{a+b+c}\right)\geq \frac{af(x_1)+bf(x_2)+cf(x_3)}{a+b+c},$$
> where $a,b,c$ are positive numbers and $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are any points in the domain.**

My attempt is:
The case if more than one point is equal can be proven using definition. So WLOG, assume that $x_1<x_2<x_3$, then $x_2=tx_1+(1-t)x_2$, for some $t \in (0,1).$ After plugging this, we can group the terms $x_1$ and$ x_2$. The coefficients of $x_1$ and $x_2$ are $\frac{a+bt}{a+b+c}$ and $\frac{b(1-t)+c}{a+b+c}$. Then we can use the definition of a concave function to 'expand' into an inequality. For the terms $f(x_1),f(x_3)$, the coefficients are as desired, but the remaining term is $\frac{btf(x_1)+b(1-t)f(x_3)}{a+b+c}.$ I almost get the inequality, but the remaining term runs the inequality in an opposite direction ($\leq$).

May someone just give some comments (small tips is enough)? Thank you.

Comment: *Hint*: Computing barycentres is associative.

Comment: See Jensen's inequality

Comment: I got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a **concave** function, Jensen's inequality says that
$$f\left(\frac{\sum_i a_ix_i}{\sum_i a_i} \right) \ge \frac{\sum_i a_i f(x_i)}{\sum_i a_i}$$
Put $a_1 = a$, $a_2 = b$, $a_3 = c$ where the sum runs over $1\le i\le 3$.

Note: If $f$ is a **convex** function, Jensen's inequality reverses and now says that
$$f\left(\frac{\sum_i a_ix_i}{\sum_i a_i} \right) \le \frac{\sum_i a_i f(x_i)}{\sum_i a_i}$$